# Google cloud storage md5 check on file

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I want to get the content md5 of my GCS file.

I tried to do this :

```
Storage.Objects.Get get = storage.objects().get(BUCKET_NAME_MUSIC_DATA, fileName);
serverHash = get.execute().getMd5Hash();
bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(get.executeMediaAsInputStream());
//process the stream
```

I get the md5 and the stream, but this technically involves 2 network calls.

Then I tried this :

```
Storage.Objects.Get get = storage.objects().get(BUCKET_NAME_MUSIC_DATA, fileName);
HttpResponse httpResponse = get.executeMedia();
serverHash = httpResponse.getHeaders().getContentMD5();
bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpResponse.getContent());
```

This is a single network call, but the hash is coming as null....
Plz help.

Comment: Does the object actually have an MD5 (you can try gsutil ls -L to verify)?  Not all Google Cloud Storage objects have an MD5.  Composite objects, for example, only have CRC32c.

Comment: yes it does ! according to this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers, content-md5 is not included in http response

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-java check out java samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution after going through the docs.
The md5 hash is in the x-goog-hash header key.
Here is the code :

```
Storage.Objects.Get get = storage.objects().get(BUCKET_NAME_APP_DATA, fileName);
HttpResponse httpResponse = get.executeMedia();
String x_goog_hash = httpResponse.getHeaders().get("x-goog-hash").toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(x_goog_hash))
    throw new IOException("Response x-goog-hash was null");

final int start = x_goog_hash.indexOf("md5=");
final int end = x_goog_hash.indexOf("==", start);

if (start == -1 || end == -1 || end <= start)
    throw new IOException("Response x-goog-hash of unexpected type " + x_goog_hash);

serverHash = x_goog_hash.substring(start + 4, end + 2);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(serverHash))
    throw new IOException("Response md5 was null");

Log.i("Ayush", "Md5 hash = ? " + serverHash);
bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpResponse.getContent());
```